# How can I CamelCase-enable Vim search?

Tags: vim

Is there a Vim plugin, script, or function out there that allows Vim search to be extended in order to match camel-cased words when I type its capital letters in succession?

Here is an example to clarify. Let’s say I am looking for `WordInQuestion`. I would like to be able to just type `/wiq` in order to find it.

As an added bonus, it would be nice if I could find `getWordInQuestion` by typing `/gwiq` which means the first letter of the word I am looking for may be lower case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The described functionality can be easily implemented by means of Vimscript.
Let us consider the following custom mappings.

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>/ SearchCamelCase('/')
nnoremap <expr> <leader>? SearchCamelCase('?')

function! SearchCamelCase(dir)
    call inputsave()
    let ab = input(a:dir)
    call inputrestore()

    let l = filter(split(toupper(ab), '\zs'), 'v:val =~ "\\w"')
    if len(l) > 0
        let l[0] = '[' . l[0] . tolower(l[0]) . ']'
    end
    let @/ = '\C\<' . join(map(l, 'v:val . "[0-9a-z_]*"'), '') . '\>'

    return a:dir . "\r"
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I changed one line in order to also match partial words e.g. myWordInQuestion should still be matched via wiq:

let @/ = '\C\<' . "\\w*" . join(map(l, 'v:val."\\w*"'), '') . '\>'

Comment: @Thorsten:  In this case it is better to change that line as follows:  `let @/ = '\C' . join(map(l, 'v:val."[0-9a-z_]*"'), '') . '\>'`.

Comment: Thanks, finally is there a way to match myWordInQuestion with mwiq as well? E.g. the first letter in the word (and only that one) I search for may be lower case?

Comment: @Thorsten:  I have updated the script to address the issue.  Please, update the question statement to reflect your changed definition of a camel-case word.

Comment: @Thorsten:  As before, to allow start of the match in the middle of a word, remove the `\<` atom from the pattern.  Similarly, to allow a match to end in the middle of the word (so that the abbreviation `ot` would match in the word `OneTwoThree`, for example), get rid of the `\>` atom.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice plugin called fuzzy finder that may be useful.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984

FuzzyFinder provides convenient ways to quickly reach the 
buffer/file/command/bookmark/tag you want. FuzzyFinder searches with a 
fuzzy/partial pattern such as camel case.